# MRAN R Server ggmap and ggplot2 dependency version 2.2.0

Tags: r, ggplot2, microsoft-r

I am using R Server in SQL Server, and I am trying to use the package `ggmap` and the `register_google` command.  However, the latest version of `ggmap` is not on CRAN yet.  When I try to use `devtools`, it fails because `ggplot2` 2.2.0 is required.  When I try to update `ggplot2`, R Server just keeps installing 1.0.1

My Microsoft R Open version is 8.0.3 from 9-7-2016.  How do I go about getting hooked up to the latest MRAN and getting `ggplot2` 2.2.0?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the repo you download from:

```
# will redirect to your nearest CRAN mirror
install.packages("ggplot2", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

I believe your version numbers are R 3.3.1, and RevoScaleR 8.0.3. Both are fairly old now. The latest is R 3.4.1 and RevoScaleR 9.1.

Check out the documentation for more methods here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/install-additional-r-packages-on-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I don't really use Microsoft R Open or RevoScaleR stuff.  I am just using the built-in R Server functionalities with SQL Server 2016.  In fact, I uninstalled R client and MRO today and can still run my R script as a SPROC on my database, so it still works.  I am still very confused how you update R Server version.

Comment: You can use SqlBindR.exe (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/use-sqlbindr-exe-to-upgrade-an-instance-of-sql-server) to upgrade the version of Microsoft R that runs within SQL Server. You need to be running SQL 2016 SP1 + GDR (or newer), install a newer standalone version of MRS on the database machine (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/r-server/install/r-server-install-windows), and then run SqlBindR.exe.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to install a standalone version.  I want the in-database as I am running on my local machine.

Comment: @Bob Albright I've gone in circles with this documentation already.  When I go to myvisualstudio.com I do not find this standalone installer anywhere...I see the option to download the entire Dev Essentials Visual Studio .exe but I already have Visual Studio on my machine.

Comment: @PabloBoswell I might have directed you to something that's not exactly what you need. To install newer packages from Microsoft R you should follow documentation here (https://mran.microsoft.com/faq/#change-repos). And to get to the Microsoft R Server downloads try this (https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=microsoft%20r%20server&pgroup=)

Comment: "I don't really use Microsoft R Open or RevoScaleR stuff. I am just using the built-in R Server functionalities with SQL Server 2016." The built-in R Server functionality IS the RevoScaleR stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution was to update R altogether.

This link talks about the `installr` package:

https://www.r-statistics.com/2015/06/a-step-by-step-screenshots-tutorial-for-upgrading-r-on-windows/

To access the `Rgui.exe`, it should be in your Program Files folder...

`R_Services` -> `bin` -> `x64`

Run the GUI as admin, then:

```
install.packages("installr")
library(installr)
```

Now the console will have a new menu dropdown for `installr`

EDIT:  This did not quite work.  Still working on it.

Comment: Did you try what I posted?

Comment: The issue is that I would have to install a standalone R server.  Do I really have to do this?  I already have the in-database Server.

Comment: I never said you had to install a standalone R server. I said to _change your install.packages call_: `install.packages("ggplot2", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")`

Comment: @Hong Ooi sorry I got your answer confused with Bob's.  Yes, I've downloaded the most recent version of ggplot2, now I get a failed namespace error...I am just going to install SQL Server 2017 and start over.  Thanks for your patience and time!